# eBay Platform Notifications SOAP Listener Issue

Tags: php, soap, ebay-api

I am trying to set-up eBay Platform Notifications using the official [PlatformNotificationsCodeSample-PHP](https://github.com/eBayDeveloper/eBay_APICall_CodeSamples/tree/master/Trading/PlatformNotifications/PlatformNotificationsCodeSample-PHP) template.

I've configured `ebay.ini` successfully with my keys and tokens.
With this, `SetNotificationPreferences.php` and `GetNotificationPreferences.php` both result in Success calls without issue.

With `GetNotificationPreferences` I can see that I successfully changed my `ApplicationURL` to http://localhost/notifications/listener.php

If I try to access `generator.php` via the command line, that returns a successful call

```
C:\development\xampp\htdocs\notifications>php generator.php
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:ns1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
  SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:GetMemberMessagesResponseResponse><return xsi:type="xsd:string">
  trachtenberga</return></ns1:GetMemberMessagesResponseResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This coming from the `$argc` `$notifications array` and `AskSellerQuestion.xml`

I am just really confused as to how `listener.php` works.

Whether I access it directly in the browser(http://localhost/notifications/listener.php), or in the command line, I always get the following error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA in C:\development\xampp\htdocs\notifications\listener.php on line 107
```

This line being:

```
$stdin = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
```

The only possible solution I've found thus far to the `Undefined index: HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` issue is to change my `php.ini` configuration to `always_populate_raw_post_data = On`, but this has no affect and I still get the same error.

I know it's been advised to use `php://input` instead since `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` was depreciated in PHP 5.6.0 and removed in PHP 7.0.0, but according to the [eBay Knowledge base](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=2032)

> Please use $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] to capture the payload
>   instead of file_get_contents(php://input). We have problems like
>   clients retrieving cut-off and incomplete payloads, when they capture
>   the PHP input stream.

How do I get this SOAP listener to work so I can start configuring my Platform Notifications?

Comment: can someone please explain me how to implement subscriber and receiver. I'm looking into writing api that would receive notifications, but how do you keep up with subscriber. I'm working .net mvc c#

how to test notifications on localhost.

Comment: This thread is about the eBay API for PHP.. I have no idea about .net mvc c#.  In my experience you simply `Enable` which platform notification you want to receive through the eBay API, and then whenever that thing you subscribed to receive, eBay will send a response to wherever you specified.  `SetNotificationPreferences` and `GetNotificationPreferences` is what I believe you want to look into further.

Comment: i'm confused about if i have to call the setnotifcationpreference everytime to check if the subscription is still enabled. Is it just one time process?

Comment: Yes you either enable it once to set it to run indefinitely or disable it.

Comment: thanks for getting back. how would i know if ebay stop sending notfications

Comment: Well I get the xml notification responses saved as an xml file, parsed and inserted into my database.. so I guess to answer your question is to pay attention? Haha. I don't know it depends on what you're trying to do and how you're doing it really.  They've been pretty stable so far and I haven't had any issues with them coming through.  But you can also use the rest of the eBay API to double-pass or double-check stuff that you're trying to do with the Platform Notifications.

Comment: that's what we are planning, to have console application to run certain time  as scheduled task to check if we are missing any updates.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot about this thread. My solution to get this to work was simply to use

```
if (!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents("php://input");
}

// then do what you want, for example I was doing something like this
// to save the xml response to my web server

$file_name= "order_shipped_".time().".xml";
$stdin = $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
file_put_contents($file_name, $stdin);
```

And I've been receiving all my notifications fine.

But with accordance to the original thread, I am not sure this is the best work-around taking into consideration the eBay Knowledge Base and the function depreciation. If anyone has any more input on this feel free to chime in :)